# How to use stream to get some fields from a list

Tags: java

I have a list of Cars. In this List have a class Car, that have fields like make, model, color, owner, plate.

And I want to get a list of Cars that have a similar make. So I want to use stream to do this.
I know how to get all car makes but not a specific kind of car make.
So if I want all the car makes I would do like

```
Cars().stream().map(Car::getMake).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if I want just the car maker that are equal to Mazda for example, how would I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `.map(Car::getMake)` you are only returning the value of `getMake` to the list.
If you need access to the whole `car` object you have to use the `filter` function on the stream.

```java
Cars().stream().filter(car -> car.getMake().equals("Mazda")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:**

Updated code based on the comments:

```java
Cars().stream()
      .filter(car -> car.getMake().equals("Mazda"))
      .map(Car::getPlate)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now seeing your answer. I think my question was not very good. I might not want the whole car object, let's say I only want the plates. So filtering by all mazdas give me a list containing the plates.

Comment: Filter the cars first and map afterwards. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But now I am trying to do the same thing again in a different class and compiler is not allowing me to use .collect(Collectors.toList()); again. i can't use that twice in the same file?

Comment: You can use `collect`once per stream. If you want to apply another filter just start over with `Cars().stream().filter(...).collect(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Using a stream to get a specific car make will work.  But have you considered using a stream to populate a map to get any list of car makes in relatively constant time?

```
record Car(String getMake, String getModel /* other attributes as required*/) {
     public String toString() {
         return "Make = %s, Model = %s".formatted(getMake(), getModel());
     }
 }
 List<Car> cars = List.of(
         new Car("Toyota", "Camry"),
         new Car("Toyota", "Corolla"),
         new Car("Mazda", "CX-9"),
         new Car("Mazda", "Mazda3"),
         new Car("Mazda", "CX-5"),
         new Car("Mazda", "CX-30"),
         new Car("Mazda", "MX-30"));
```

The following groups the cars by make and puts them in a list for that make.

```
Map<String, List<Car>> carMakes = 
   cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getMake));
 
List<Car> mazda = carMakes.get("Mazda");
System.out.println("All Mazdas");
mazda.forEach(System.out::println);

List<Car> toyotas = carMakes.get("Toyota");
System.out.println("All Toyotas");
toyotas.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
All Mazdas
Make = Mazda, Model = CX-9
Make = Mazda, Model = Mazda3
Make = Mazda, Model = CX-5
Make = Mazda, Model = CX-30
Make = Mazda, Model = MX-30
All Toyotas
Make = Toyota, Model = Camry
Make = Toyota, Model = Corolla
```